# Каков правильный подход в изучении программирования на Java?

Tags: java

Изучаю Java, дошел до multithreading, хочу написать блог, пусть хоть самый убогий, а потом дополнять его чем-то (если это вообще возможно на Java, в чем я сомневаюсь, так как не нашел в google таких статей). Но я не понимаю, что надо сделать мне, с чего начать. Смотреть чужой код как мне кажется не очень, так как ты получаешь в таком случае второсортные знания. Что Вы мне можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 3):

1. Прочитать книгу по Java
2. Написать какой то проект(строго по ТЗ, а не как получится)
3. Прочитать книгу ещё раз(либо другую книгу)

Самый лучший способ изучения.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю это верный путь на 2020.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

взято [отсюда](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2019/10/the-java-developer-roadmap.html)